# How to override division by zero algorithm?

Tags: php

Instead of division by zero I want to divide by 1 for example? To prevent getting warning or INF value.

```
<?php
echo 4 / 0;
```

results INF, I want to get 4 in whole app which have many calculations

Comment: Why don't you check if the divisor is 0 and change it to 1 if so?

Comment: there is too many divisions in app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the wrapper `MathHelper` with methods

- `safeDivInt(int $dividend, int $divisor): int`
- `safeDivFloat(float $dividend, float $divisor): float`

and refactor your app